# How to configure Windows 2008 R2 for receive asp.NET webapps deployment

Tags: asp.net, deployment, windows-server-2008

I've tried to follow tutorials but all the ones I've found are incomplete and I've been unsuccessful in deploying an asp.net web-app on a Windows 2008 R2 Server.

I've installed all the necessary package (IIS, web deploy service), but I get an error when I try to deploy.

Anyone know a good tutorial to start configuring the server?

I'm running Windows 2008 R2 Web Edition. The client for develop are Windows 7 machine and I need to deploy ON Windows 2008 Server Web edition.

Comment: Ok. I started from scratch and now I'm able to publish without error, but when I try to access to the webapp path (http://serverIPaddress/ne) I've got a message 403 Access Denied

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble deploying my app too. Lots of incomplete information or assumptions made in in tutorials. Why is it so hard? :(. If you ended up getting this working by following some guide please post.

Comment: What kind of troubles do you have? Because after I did several attempts I have a full working system now. If I can help you...

Comment: Yea I asked my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232026/deploying-an-asp-net-application-on-iis-7-error-when-creating-virtual-folder